# Creating users in the database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, orm

Im modeling database tables for register/login pages. At the first insert all ends without any errors, but following insert return IntegrityError exception:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "mainws_user_role_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (role_id)=(1) already exists.

If OneToOneField making rows only as unique, it means, that I cant create many users with one role, right? Then better using `ForeignKey(Role)` for this situation, or not?

Source code:

```
class User(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = models.EmailField()
    role = models.OneToOneField(Role, primary_key=False)

class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)

def create_user(user_data):
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    md5.update(user_data['password'])
    user_role = Role.objects.filter(role_name='user')[0]
    password_md5 = md5.hexdigest()
    new_user = User(login=user_data['login'],password=password_md5,address=user_data['address'],
                    phone=user_data['phone'],postcode=user_data['postcode'],
                    email=user_data['email'],role=user_role)
    new_user.save()
```

Comment: use set_foreign_key_checks=0 in your database settings.

Comment: **Don't** roll your own auth and hash your passwords with MD5. Django includes an authentication framework with a far more secure password storage. You should use it.

Comment: you might need a `session.commit()` after saving it ... I cant remember with django orm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think your issue is in the OneToOneField. As its name implies, you can only associate one role with one user. A foreign key represents a ManyToOne relationship, that is what you want in this case, many users can have one role.

On the other hand, you are trying to create users on your own when Django already has most of that by default. Frameworks are there to avoid you making sensitive parts of your application manually.

You may want to check [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-permissions) if you don't know how to do that.